# M2Eclipse, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I use the M2Eclipse plugin in Eclipse.

And I don't know for what reason, each time I import a Maven project in Eclipse, it always generates an empty 
- src/main/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file (jar-packaged projects)
- src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file (war-packaged projects)

I find this a bit annoying ;-) Does someone know how to disable this behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-66?focusedCommentId=132610&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-132610) in m2e-wtp 0.13.0. Latest m2e-wtp version can be found at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

The root cause of the problem is WTP's Dynamic Web Facet, which automatically creates a MANIFEST.MF when it's installed. m2e-wtp now removes the file if it was created by WTP, but leaves any existing MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by the WTP addon for m2eclipse. If you aren't using it, try uninstalling the WTP Extras.

Answer (score 1):

It's non-maven behaviour which I think is down to WTP being 'naughty'.  It really shouldn't add anything to your source folders, and also this behaviour should not just happen to pick one of a number of source folders. I've seen it add this to src/test/java too.